# Cursor replacement script breaks when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I found a little cursor replacement script that looks kewl and works really well on full-screen pages. I implemented it on my wordpress website, but I realized that when I'm on a page where I have to scroll, my cursor image doesn't stay attached to where my actual pointer is. Scrolling doesn't update the cursor's position to my mouse pointer.

I tried adding an eventlistener for onscroll to update the cursor's position when I scroll, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I also tried putting my cursor div into another div, and set that one's position to sticky, but that just broke the whole thing.

Here are two links where you can see the script in action :

[krauss.fr/about](http://krauss.fr/about) (on this page it works fine)
[krauss.fr/works](http://krauss.fr/works) (on this page it doesn't)

And here's my code

```
function setCurrentCursorProps() {

// Apply translation (set to actual cursor position)
cursorEl.style.transform = `translate(${currentCursorPos.x}px, ${currentCursorPos.y}px)`;

// Ensure correct rotation transition direction
while (Math.abs(lastCursorAngle - cursorAngle) > 180) {
  if (cursorAngle > lastCursorAngle) {
    cursorAngle -= 360;
  } else if (cursorAngle < lastCursorAngle) {
    cursorAngle += 360;
  }
}

// Apply rotation
cursorImageEl.style.transform = `rotate(${cursorAngle - 90}deg)`;
}

function updateCursor() {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
    currentCursorPos = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
    });
    window.addEventListener('onscroll', event => { //this is the code I added that doesn't work
    currentCursorPos = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
    }); 

// Interval for updating cursor-position
setInterval(setCurrentCursorProps, INTERVAL_POSITION);

// Interval for updating cursor-rotation
setInterval(() => {
const delt = {
x: lastCursorPos.x - currentCursorPos.x,
y: lastCursorPos.y - currentCursorPos.y };

if (Math.abs(delt.x) < 3 && Math.abs(delt.y) < 3) return;
cursorAngle = Math.atan2(delt.y, delt.x) * 180 / Math.PI;

setCurrentCursorProps();

lastCursorPos = currentCursorPos;
lastCursorAngle = cursorAngle;
}, INTERVAL_ROTATION);
}


return {

'initialize': () => {
   cursorEl = document.querySelector('#cursor');
  cursorImageEl = document.querySelector('#cursor > img');
  updateCursor();
} };

}();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', rotatingCursor.initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the event is not `onscroll` but `scroll`:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', event => {
    alert("Nice scroll !")
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div><div/>
```

You will find more infos here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp